# Can't load cake module - Preprocessor directive expected

Tags: powershell, cakebuild

I'm trying to run a cake build script that loads a module for long file path but it only returns 
**error CS1024: Preprocessor directive expected**

In the cake file I have added
`#module nuget:?package=Cake.LongPath.Module&version=0.5.0`
and this is the line where I get the error at (1,2)

[In the docs](https://cakebuild.net/docs/fundamentals/preprocessor-directives) It states that this is the format and that I should run the script with `--bootstrap` before actually running the script. Running `` Invoke-Expression "& `"$CAKE_EXE`" `"$Script`" --bootstrap" `` causes a the error and then I also get it on the line after when running it without the --bootstrap flag.

What I need is to make sure that **Cake.LongPath** module is installed and loaded in CI. Any thoughts on other solutions would also be helpful

Comment: Can you confirm what version of Cake you are using?

Comment: Can you confirm that this is the command that you are running `Invoke-Expression "& `"$CAKE_EXE`" `"$Script`" --bootstrap"` Notice that the bootstrap argument is actually outside of the Invoke-Expression, which is not correct.

Comment: Write-Host outputs: `& "C:\...\Cake.exe" "build.cake" --bootstrap`. Cake version is set to 0.18 in packages.config though, so I guess it's quiet old.
Tried using #load for the nuget package and it swallowed it, but not sure if it actually works

Comment: The #load directive is intended for loading in other .cake files, or nuget packages that contain .cake files, not for modules or anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--bootstrap` command was only added in Version 0.24.0 of Cake.  You can see the release notes here:

https://github.com/cake-build/cake/releases/tag/v0.24.0

And the issue that it was worked on here:

https://github.com/cake-build/cake/issues/1950

I am fairly sure that this issue will be solved by upgrading to a newer version of Cake.  This can be done by changing the version number in the packages.config file, and by clearing out the tools folder.  **NOTE**:  Depending on what version of the bootstrapper you are using, the clearing out of the tools folder may be done for you automatically.

Comment: Yes, just updated and tried and it seems to work, should have been the first thing I tried but sometimes the easy solutions slip your mind